# Why does Jenkins think I'm a guest when I'm an administrator?

Tags: cloudbees

Just this morning, I was able to log into [my Cloudbees Jenkins Dashboard](https://gedcom.ci.cloudbees.com/) and configure builds, start builds, etc. But now I log in and it considers me a "guest user" and I can't kick off a build. What's up?

[image: dashboard]
[image: at /configure]

Comment: A few questions: 1) Is this a FOSS account? 2) Can you attach a screen shot? 3) Try going to /manage to see if you are prompted to login.

Comment: What happens if you click the "Access gedcom" link in the toolbar?

Comment: Ah! That worked! I didn't even realize that was a link. Thanks for your help. Was there some kind of recent change? I've never had to click that link before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your Jenkins session has expired, but the toolbar is not showing the "Login" link. As a workaround, you can just navigate to /manage or /configure, and you will be prompted to login. We are working on a fix for this.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't resolve the issue for me--it doesn't appear to be a session issue. I've tried to hit /manage or /configure, but I just get some kind of Content Encoding error. I've also tried clearing my cookies and logging in again. This is a FOSS account.